# Can the Fourier Transform come out of other group representations?

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Let $V$ be the $p$ dimensional vector space of functions from $\mathbb{F}_p  $ to the $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\hat{f}$ be the discrete fourier transform of $f$.    There exists a representation, namely, the Weil Representation, $\rho: SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p) \to GL(V) $ where $\rho (\omega)(f) = \hat{f} $

where $\omega=  
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 &1 \\
   -1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
\ $.

I was curious if there were other (interesting) group representations $V$ for which some element acted as the fourier transform.

Comment: Only a single element in the range of the representation is used, so really this just says the Fourier transform is a linear operator. The transform is automatically linear, but for for $f$ and $\hat{f}$ to be in the same function space the original abelian topological group must be self-dual, which $\Bbb F_p$ and $\Bbb R$ are. But, for instance, $S^1$ and $\Bbb Z$ are each other's duals (not self-dual), so the transform is instead between function spaces $L^2(S^1)\leftrightarrow L^2(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Yes I answered the question of when $f$ and $\hat{f}$ were in the same function space, that is indeed a thing I was pointing out for the sake of having it pointed out. As for the other thing I was pointing out: The Fourier transform on a vector space $V$ is, if we assume an isomorphism between $V$ and functions on $V$, already some linear operation $F\in GL(V)$, so you're basically asking if there there is a representation $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ of any group $G$ that has a given element $F\in GL(V)$ in its range. But $F$ isn't arbitrary, so it might help to narrow down what it can be.